# Rename [bootcamp] → [boot-camp]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-rename-request

Apple's [Boot Camp](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1461) is two words, so I'd like to request that the tag [bootcamp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootcamp) be renamed [boot-camp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot-camp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds reasonable to me. Done.